how to parse java type com.oracle.truffle into list,string,object
the goal is to parse the inputed data into its correct format.
the issue is that the data type is of some sort of com.oracle.truffle
code::
   private Object convertJSValueToJava(Object jsValue) {
        System.out.println("jsValue: " + jsValue + " Type: " + jsValue.getClass().getName());
        if (jsValue instanceof Value) {
            Value value = (Value) jsValue;
            if (value.isNull()) {
                return null;
            } else if (value.isBoolean()) {
                System.out.println("bool output ");
                return value.asBoolean();
            } else if (value.isNumber()) {
                return value.asDouble();
            } else if (value.isString()) {
                System.out.println("string output ");
                return value.asString();
            } else if (value.hasArrayElements()) {
                System.out.println("arr list output ");

                List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < value.getArraySize(); i++) {
                    list.add(convertJSValueToJava(value.getArrayElement(i)));
                }
                return list;
            } else if (value.hasMembers()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                for (String key : value.getMemberKeys()) {
                    map.put(key, convertJSValueToJava(value.getMember(key)));
                }
                return map;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("default to string");
        return jsValue.toString(); // Default to string representation if type is unknown
    }


output:
jsValue: ["default_sys_properties"] Type: com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList
default to string

I never seen the data type com.oracle.truffle, not sure why the script is not able to correctly identify it.
If i turn the input into a string and classify it based on its first and last characters i can correctly label arrays and objects.
but for other data types it can get messy.
these are my dependecies::
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
            <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>


there is only one stackoverflow that mentions com.oracle.truffle which is super weird:

I was expecting to find the information on the oracle website but its missing my info:
https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/com/oracle/truffle/api/package-summary.html


The type is not com.oracle.truffle, the type is com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList.
